# Pronouncing 'Going' in UK English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

How to pronounce 'going' in UK english?
As per phonetics 'go' is pronounced as 'go-v' 
So when we add 'ing' whether we have to pronounce it 'go-v-ing'or just 'going'?

Comment: There is no "v" in ***go*** or ***going*** in any speech variant I know of. Why do you say this is "as per phonetics"?

Comment: No, _go_ is **never, ever, in any dialect or any kind of phonetic writing** written as being pronounced “go-v”. There is no v-sound of any kind in that word, ever. In standard, Received Pronunciation-like British English, _go_ is pronounced approximately [ɡəʊ] or [ɡɜʊ], and _going_ is pronounced [ˈɡəʊ.ɪŋ] or [ˈɡɜʊ.ɪŋ] (the final [ŋ] can also be just [n], depending on speed, context, and clarity).

Comment: Most speakers in at least some contexts reduce the first vowel in *gonna = going to* to a schwa, but it's also quite common to "elevate" it to rhyme with ***gun***.

Comment: *go* is pronounced with a /w/, and not a /v/. (These are the same consonant in some languages, but not English.) And when we say *going*, indeed we put in the /w/. But if you put in a /v/ instead of a /w/, you'll confuse people more than if leave out both the /w/ and the /v/.

Comment: What I think this question is asking (and it is relevant for all varieties of English, not just BrE), is how to really pronounce word or morpheme transitions from (semi-)vowel to (semi-)vowel. Do you remove the glide (at the end of 'go'), do you remove it, do you replace with a glottal stop, do you convert to a diphthong, or what?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you mean by "As per phonetics 'go' is pronounced as 'go-v'".

I can think of no English accent in which "go" has a /v/ (voiced labiodental fricative) sound.

However, in many accents the vowel in 'go' is a diphthong, in which the second element is a mid-high rounded approximant /ʊ/ (roughly, the vowel in 'look' or 'put'): is that what you mean? In those accents, the diphthong remains in 'going'.

Comment: Since "you de man", so to speak, can I just ask what word (if any) linguists would use to describe what I just referred to as "elevating" the first vowel sound in *gonna* so it rhymes with *gun?*

Comment: _Raising_, I think, and perhaps _fronting_ a bit, from (low) mid to upper-mid.

Answer (score 0):

It's goin', put less stress on last 'g'. Here's a link that you can refer to listen it [,click here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/going)

Comment: There is no last 'g': that is a purely orthographic device for representing the sound /ŋ/. What you refer to as "put less stress on last 'g'" is more accurately described as "substitute the phoneme /n/ for the different phoneme /ŋ/".